# SQL Select Distinct Values, but order by a different value

Tags: sql, distinct

I want to select all distinct order_ids from my table, and order that list by the date column. Using DISTINCT is of course a query-wide parameter, so trying something like this doesn't work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(orderId, datetime) 
FROM table 
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

This returns all DISTINCT combinations of the orderId and datetime, so I'm left with multiple orderIds, which I don't want. Therefore I'm thinking that the DISTINCT clause is not the way to go. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If there are multiple rows for the order, which date do you want to show? perhaps:

```
SELECT [orderId], MAX([datetime])
FROM [table]
GROUP BY [orderId]
ORDER BY MAX([datetime]) DESC
```

Comment: As a follow up, what if I wanted to select all values in the table, not just orderId and datetime? I have a feeling that's a totally separate questions, but...

Comment: You would need to either aggregate all the columns, or select a particular row (min(id), max(id), or similar) and do a join / sub-query.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a CTE would help:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(

SELECT orderId FROM table ORDER BY datetime DESC

)

SELECT DISTINCT orderId  FROM CTE
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, for a moment i forgot that this is not the MSDN SQL forum :)

Comment: Says "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.".

Comment: Does SQL Server guarantee the ordering of the CTE to be maintained? Seems like a very risky internal thing to rely on, if it even works. Especially since there are formally correct solutions, that *guarantee* the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 
  (SELECT value1 
   FROM table1 
   ORDER BY value2);
```

That worked for me.

Comment: This is incorrect. The database is free to ignore the derived table's `ORDER BY` clause, which it will effectively do when `DISTINCT` is implemented using hashing, e.g. in a more complex query. Your concrete database optimiser implementation may have *accidentally* produced the desired result, but you must not rely on it!