# SQL Server - SELECT all values in table without having them in the GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by

So this question might have already been answered, but it's a bit difficult to search for or even to ask it.

I want to query a table and filter it in a number of ways. In the example below, I want to figure out who the first employee was for each dept.

Example Table Below `Table A`

```
employee_id  |  dept_id  |  start_date  |  name  |  age  | sex
          1  |        1  |    1/5/2000  |   Bill |   25  |  m                 
          2  |        2  |    2/5/2000  |   Biff |   30  |  m                
          3  |        2  |    3/6/2002  |   Gil  |   31  |  m                 
          4  |        2  |    3/7/2002  |   Mar  |   27  |  f                    
          5  |        3  |    1/5/2000  |   Tina |   24  |  f                           
          6  |        3  |    1/5/2000  |   Lin  |   21  |  f
```

So if I do `SELECT dept_id, min(start_date) from Table A GROUP BY dept_id ORDER BY min(start_date)`

I'll get

```
dept_id  |  start_date 
      1  |    1/5/2000                
      2  |    2/5/2000                       
      3  |    1/5/2000
```

Which is correct information, except I need the other columns. I can't just add them to the SELECT statement because they aren't in the GROUP BY, and I can't just add them to the GROUP BY because then I won't get the correct results.

This comment sort of answered my question, but not fully [SQL Select Distinct Values, but order by a different value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785501/sql-select-distinct-values-but-order-by-a-different-value#comment1672616_1785515) 
because I tried doing a subquery inside a join and adding the fields in the SELECT, but it still wanted the fields to be in the GROUP BY.

Please Advise

EDIT:
 The results I'd like to get are

```
employee_id |  dept_id  |  start_date  |  name  |  age  | sex
          1 |        1  |    1/5/2000  |   Bill |   25  |  m                 
          2 |        2  |    2/5/2000  |   Biff |   30  |  m                
          5 |        3  |    1/5/2000  |   Tina |   24  |  f
```

Comment: Please be specific on the other fields you want.  Right now, you wanted the earliest date a person started by depart id.  Clear business rules helps us give you a clear answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `row_number()`:

```
select employee_id, dept_id, start_date, name, age, sex
from (select a.*, row_number() over (partition by dept_id order by start_date) as seqnum
      from table a
     ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```

`row_number()` is a function that assigns sequential numbers to groups of rows.  The groups are defined by the `partition by` clause, so in this case everyone in the same department is in the same group.  The numbers are assigned in order based on the `order by` clause.  So, the earliest start date gets a value of 1.  The `where` clause then chooses these records.

Answer (score 2):

to find out 1st person for each dept

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(employee_id INT,dept_id INT,[start_date] DATE
  ,name VARCHAR(10),age INT, sex CHAR(1))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
(1,1,'1/5/2000','Bill',25,'m'),                 
(2,2,'2/5/2000','Biff',30,'m'),                
(3,2,'3/6/2002','Gil',31,'m'),                 
(4,2,'3/7/2002','Mar',27,'f'),                    
(5,3,'1/5/2000','Tina',24,'f'),                           
(6,3,'1/5/2000','Lin',21,'f')

SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT * 
    , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dept_id ORDER BY [start_date] ASC) 
  FROM @Table
 )Q
WHERE rn = 1
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═════════════╦═════════╦════════════╦══════╦═════╦═════╦════╗
║ employee_id ║ dept_id ║ start_date ║ name ║ age ║ sex ║ rn ║
╠═════════════╬═════════╬════════════╬══════╬═════╬═════╬════╣
║           1 ║       1 ║ 2000-01-05 ║ Bill ║  25 ║ m   ║  1 ║
║           2 ║       2 ║ 2000-02-05 ║ Biff ║  30 ║ m   ║  1 ║
║           5 ║       3 ║ 2000-01-05 ║ Tina ║  24 ║ f   ║  1 ║
╚═════════════╩═════════╩════════════╩══════╩═════╩═════╩════╝
```